# changing date format from dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datepicker which shows date in format dd/MM/yyyy(i know i coould change there itself but by client want it that way) and in database its in format MM/dd/yyyy so i do want to convert in that way.

e.g. in text box 23/09/2010 and in c sharp its convert to mm/dd/yyyy(txtbo1.text)

Regards
Indranil.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really store the date as a string in the DB, you can convert the string format in the following manner:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: So @David M solution is better. The parsing can be done as I've said but you don't need the DateTime as a different string (you don't need to do ToString()).

Comment: DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

Now you need to take that dateTime and put it as a parameter for the SQL command. If you want to write it directly in the SQL string, you'll probably still need to do dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

Answer (score 8):

If you are storing dates in a database, you should be storing them in a field with an appropriate data type. The format shouldn't come into it. You should parse your dd/MM/yyyy text into a DateTime variable, and pass it in a parameters of a date/time type to your database.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
    public static String DMYToMDY(String input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input,
        @"\b(?<day>\d{1,2})/(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<year>\d{2,4})\b",
        "${month}/${day}/${year}");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 using System.Globalization;

 string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text.Trim()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

also can be done with this

```
 public string FormatPostingDate(string str)
 {
     if (str != null && str != string.Empty)
     {
         DateTime postingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(str);
         return string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", postingDate);
     }
     return string.Empty;
 }
```