# C#: How to take date string of MM/DD/YYYY and turn it into YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [changing date format from dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882070/changing-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

I have a string field whose date is presented as MM/DD/YYYY but I need it to be YYYY-MM-DD.

Here is the what it looks like:

```
DateReported = (e.Attribute("hciIIDateReported")
```

I thought that maybe I could do a string.Format() but I cannot find a custom date and time format string that only gives YYYY-MM-DD.  The one's I have found in that format come with the time, which won't work.  Any advice?

Comment: Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I nearly voted for this as a duplicate as per Henk's post, but noticed that you said you "cannot find a custom date and time format string that only gives YYYY-MM-DD". That seems odd to me - did you read the [MSDN documentation for custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)?

Importantly, you should almost certainly be both parsing and formatting with the invariant culture; normally you would use custom format patterns with the invariant culture (or some other known, fixed culture) and standard format patterns with a user's culture.

So, you want something like:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
string formatted = parsed.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
```

However, I would *strongly* advise you to keep the value as a `DateTime` for as long as possible. Do you definitely need it as a string *right away*? You should really only be converting back to a string at API boundaries where you're absolutely *forced* to do so, IMO. Every conversion you add is a potential source of errors.

As a side matter, if you want to use a rather richer set of date/time types, you might want to consider my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library, where you could keep this value as a `LocalDate` which makes it clear it doesn't have a time component...

Also note that if these are user-entered values which may not be valid, you should consider using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) instead.

Comment: Can this be done within a LINQ to SQL select statement?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie: I doubt it - and I would recommend against trying. Fetch the data as `DateTime` values instead. Where does a database come into things? You haven't mentioned anything vaguely related to LINQ to SQL in your question.

Comment: I'm pulling XML data from one DB, and then translating it to a .csv file for input into another database.  I didn't mention LINQ to SQL because I thought I would be able to do something like string.Format( {whatever here}, e.Attribute("hciIIDateReported")).

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie: But the `e.Attribute` call suggests you've already pulled the data from the database at that point...

Comment: Yes.  At this point I am assigning the xml column name, e.Attribute("hciIIDateReported"), to column name of the database I am sending the data to, DateReported

Comment: I'm sure I've made myself look like a complete retard with this post but I learned nothing at all about with LINQ to SQL or XML  in school and am doing the best I can.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie: Basically it's *very* unclear what you're trying to achieve, but I'd keep LINQ to SQL out of the picture for the moment: transform the data locally instead, and it'll make your code a lot simpler. However, if you want standard XML dates, you can create an element with that content very easily: `new XElement("someName", dateTimeValue)` - you don't need to provide the format yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it first:

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2012");
```

if you're not using the UK locale, you'll need to add:

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2012", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

And then spit it out

```
string output = datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: *Don't* just use `DateTime.Parse` like this - it becomes ambiguous between MM/dd/yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy; then use yyyy-MM-dd instead of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @Jon updated, I admit I had to check MSDN first

Comment: You've still got the wrong year specifier, and it's now definitely going to parse it as dd/MM/yyyy which isn't what the OP wanted. Using a custom format pattern is much clearer IMO.

Comment: @Jon doesn't he want YYYY for the result? I agree though, using an invariant culture (funny how that's the same as the US culture) is cleaner.

Comment: I suspect the OP actually wants the year. Using YYYY will give exactly that "YYYY" in the output. The custom format character for years is y, not Y.

Comment: @jon thanks, fixed it. Should've checked my own blog post reference on this first

Comment: It's still got the problem that the OP wants MM/dd/yyyy as the input format string, which *isn't* how the UK culture will parse... You could change UK to US, although as we've agreed, it's cleaner to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Try `DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

**EDIT** after comments:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateString, @"MM\/dd\/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I forgot that the slash (`/`) has a special meaning in date format strings. Now it's escaped, and this seems to work. I tried it.

However, it's more safe to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as "provider" instead of the current culture (which is what you get with `null`). Then one will not have to worry that some exotic culture exists in which the result is different.

Comment: That will use the current culture to determine the date separator when parsing; almost certainly not a good idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can see why it's more "static" to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of just `null`. But won't the slashes in my string `"MM/dd/yyyy"` give the desired "date separator"?

Comment: They'll use the current thread's date separator... and thus fail to parse the string if the current thread's date separator isn't `/`, I'd expect. When you know that the string's format is in one specific culture, always make sure you use that culture for parsing (and formatting).

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. I actually thought of `/` as just a "literal" character. Like with e.g. `"MM!dd!yyyy"` it would have worked, but `/` obviously gets substituted (is a special character). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateReported.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

EDIT: this is assuming that DateReported is of type DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to MSDN custom format strings;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.71).aspx

Now if you can build your own like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

In your case if you want to print out DateReported this will be:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateReported.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for sure

```
string DateReported = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Attribute("hciIIDateReported"), "MM/dd/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Laraba I tried it but receive a "The best overloaded method match for System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: i've tried it its working perfectly, but be careful of the casing& try "M/d/yyyy" instead of "MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: this error is generated due to the input date  `e.Attribute("hciIIDateReported")` check also that is doesn't contain special characters like '\n' ...

Answer (score -3):

If you have only that field already, string processing might be the most straightforward way:

```
string processDate(string inputDate) // inputdate is like "02/05/1995"
{
    string [] fields = inputdate.Split('/');
    return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", fields[2], fields[0], fields[1]);
}
```

I think that'll work.  If you can convert it to a DateTime first, some of the other answers work too.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to me. There are perfectly good parsing and formatting routines in .NET - why go through a non-validating path?

Comment: Because quite frankly if they're not going that way already (validating via DateTime locales), then it gets them there.  Sometimes "getting there" is a way higher priority than doing it right.  It hurts every time, but that's how it goes in some (many) organizations.

Comment: But it's *easy* to do it right - so why not do so? I agree that sometimes "easy and wrong" takes priority over "hard and right" but in this case we can go with "easy and right"...